# Changing an HTML file through Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I have an HTML form (in a very basic Flask site, adjusted to be inside a class), which takes in some values and will upload them to a database. What I'd like is to send the user some kind of a message on the same page after they click the 'submit' input button. That is - not to serve up a *different* HTML file, but to change, say one of the divs  in my home.html file, or add a new div. At the moment I've thought of two possiblities:

- A JS script, with onclick() to change the InnerHTML of one of the divs;
- Serving up a new, almost identical HTML file, with one line changed to say something like "information received".

However, I have a feeling that there's a simpler way to do this, within the same file (home.html) using a method of Flask. I've spent a while searching through the docs and SO, without success.

```
class UI:
    def __init__(self):
        app = Flask(__name__)

        @app.route('/')
        def home():
            return render_template("home.html")

        @app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
        def update_info():
            foo = request.form['foo']
            bar = request.form['bar']
            if request.method == 'POST':
                 return render_template("new_home.html")

        app.debug = True
        app.run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A JS script, with onclick() to change the InnerHTML of one of the divs;

This would be the best option in my opinion. Create a `div` to contain the message above the form--or anywhere else you'd want it. I would suggest using [`jQuery`](https://jquery.com/) for this as it's [`ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) method is very nice for this type of thing. Return either a success or failure response from your app(setting the status code, so `jQuery` knows what happened), and use the `done` promise to display success or the `fail` promise to display errors.